# git ignore folders in my case

Tags: git, github, gitignore

My project contains the following directories:

```
moduleA/jars/
moduleB/jars/
moduleC/jars/
...
```

I want git to **ignore** all those `jars/` folders, so I created a ***.gitignore*** file with the following content:

```
**/jars
```

Then I commited & pushed everything to remote git repository. But I still see all those `jars/` folders in remote git repository, why?

Comment: If its already added to git it won't get affected. But for new `/jars` it will ignore.

Comment: Then, how to get rid of it? I want /jars to be ignored

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

First, if those folders are already committed, you need to remove them (from the Git repo, not from the disk, hence the `--cached` option):

```
find . -type d -name jars -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -r -f --ignore-unmatch
```

Second, to ignore a folder, its line in the `.gitignore` needs to ends with a '/'

```
jars/
```